Can an index be redefined prior to a rebuild?
Suppose that my server has a job that sometimes rebuilds indexes based on factors that I don't control (e.g. fragmentation). Suppose also that I am sure that it will one day rebuild an index that I'm interested in changing. Is there any way to instruct SQL Server that I want to change the WITH of an index upon its next rebuild, without rebuilding it right now?
For example, suppose that PK_HugeTable is set to fill factor 25. On its next rebuild, I want to set it to 100. If I do not want to rebuild the index right now, what do I do?
ALTER INDEX [...] SET works for some options, but not fill factor.

nope
You can't pre-load that sort of thing. The "best" you can do is prevent changes, but even that is quite limited to rolling back disallowed changes.
Perhaps a CLR trigger would work, but I don't have the moxie to gin all that up on a Sunday morning.
I wrote about that a bit here.

Can You Stop People From Creating SQL Server Indexes With Low Fill Factors?


Just make sure you understand something: this doesn’t stop the index
from being created, it only rolls creation back afterwards.
If someone creates a gigantic index on an equally gigantic table,
you’re in for a hell of a ride. I’d probably only deploy this on local
dev boxes, and only if I really needed to prove a point.

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER 
    CheckFillFactor
ON ALL SERVER
FOR 
    CREATE_INDEX, 
    ALTER_INDEX
AS
DECLARE 
    @FillFactor nvarchar(MAX) = N'',
    @Percent integer = NULL;

SELECT 
    @FillFactor = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)');

IF UPPER(@FillFactor) LIKE N'%FILLFACTOR%'
BEGIN
    SET @FillFactor = REPLACE(@FillFactor, N' ', N'');

    SELECT 
        @FillFactor = 
            SUBSTRING
            (
                @FillFactor, 
                CHARINDEX(N'FILLFACTOR=', @FillFactor) + LEN(N'FILLFACTOR='), 
                PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @FillFactor) + 2
            );
    
    IF TRY_CONVERT(integer, @FillFactor) IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @Percent = LEFT(@FillFactor, 2);
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Percent = @FillFactor;
    END;
    IF @Percent < 80
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('WHY YOU DO THAT?', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
END;
GO

It's a sad state of affairs. Your only contraceptive option would be permissions-based, but that may also break other parts of the application.
